# Double Linked List Constructor

Tags: java, generics, constructor, linked-list, doubly-linked-list

For an assignment, I have to write a constructor for a double linked list. The professor did not give me any big hints with this, and I am struggling to satisfy the guidelines he issued. I am supposed to write the constructor in a way that allows me to create a linked list with three nodes without using any method calls. I am only allowed to use "new", variable declarations, and assignment statements.

The linked list should look like this:

```
          +---+---+---+     +---+---+---+     +---+---+---+
list ---> |   |   | *-+---> |   |   | *-+---> |   |   | *-+--X
          |   | 1 |   |     |   | 2 |   |     |   | 3 |   |
       X--+-* |   |   | <---+-* |   |   | <---+-* |   |   |
          +---+---+---+     +---+---+---+     +---+---+---+
```

From what I have figured out so far, I would have to create all three DLNodes in one large variable declaration. This code snippet is similar to what he wants my declaration to look like, but it will not work with the current constructor.

```
DLNode<Integer> list = new DLNode<Integer>(1, null, DLNode<Integer>(2, /* pointer to the first node */, DLNode<Integer>(3, /* pointer to the second node */, null)))
```

Here is the code:

```
public class DLNode<T> {
  private T element;
  private DLNode<T> next;
  private DLNode<T> previous;

  public DLNode(T element, DLNode<T> previous, DLNode<T> next) {
    /* You need to write the correct code here to create a correctly formed 
    double linked list */
    this.element = element;
    this.previous = previous;
    this.next = next;
  }

  public T getElement() {
    return element;
  }

  public DLNode<T> getNext() {
    return next;
  }

  public void setNext(DLNode<T> next) {
    this.next = next;
  }

  public DLNode<T> getPrevious() {
    return previous;
  }

  public void setPrevious(DLNode<T> previous) {
    this.previous = previous;
  }
}
```

I put in the obvious field assignments already, but after that, he claims that I still need a couple of lines of code to make this work. We have been learning linked lists, abstract data types, iterators, for-each loops, comparable interfaces, and generics lately, but I can't find a hint for what I am supposed to do in my notes. Any help would be immensely appreciated.

Just for reference, I am using DrJava as my IDE, and it has an interactions pane that allows me to test code fragments without having to write a main method and run the code. I can just compile and then test.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. This is not a homework completion service. Your instructor gave you the assignment, not us, and you're going to need to do your own work. If we do it for you, you don't learn anything. If you can't get started, ask your teacher for additional help; they're being paid to teach you. Good luck.

Comment: If you want to chain them in one statement, you can do something like this: `DLNode(T element, DLNode<T> next) { this.element = element; this.next = next; if (next != null) next.previous = this; }`

Comment: @KenWhite I don't want you to simply complete my homework, I am looking for someone to help explain to me an issue I don't understand. I have spent many hours trying to figure this out, and I figured that, seeing the effort I have put into this post, it would be clear that I don't want you to just do my homework for me. I have exhausted google and my textbook trying to figure this out, so I was hoping that Stack Overflow might be able to help me tonight. Otherwise, I do plan on going to see my instructor tomorrow.

Comment: You need to get clarification from the instructor.  "Write a constructor" is a completely different task from "Populate the list with these 3 nodes".  The second task is incompatible with "without using any method calls".  I suspect you have not understood the assignment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I figured out how to do it once a friend gave me a hint. I had half of the constructor issue solved. The problem was that since this is a double linked list, it wasn't enough to just have the linked list node that I was creating pointing to the other nodes in front of or behind it in the double linked list. I needed to make it so that, when a new double linked list node was created, it not only pointed to the other nodes in the double linked list, but also changed the pointers in of the nodes that it was pointing to.

Basically, if I create a new double linked list node object named node1 and have it point to another double linked list object named node2, I also have to change the pointer of node2 so that it is pointing back to node1.

Here is the final code, along with some code fragments that I used to test it.

```
public class DLNode<T> {
  private T element;
  private DLNode<T> next;
  private DLNode<T> previous;

  public DLNode(T element, DLNode<T> previous, DLNode<T> next) {
     /* You need to write the correct code here to create a correctly formed 
     double linked list */
    this.element = element;
    if (next != null) {
      next.setPrevious(this);
      this.next = next;
    }
    if (previous != null) {
      previous.setNext(this);
      this.previous = previous;
    }
    if (previous == null) {
      this.previous = previous;
    }
    if (next == null) {
      this.next = next;
    }
  }

  public T getElement() {
    return element;
  }

  public DLNode<T> getNext() {
    return next;
  }

  public void setNext(DLNode<T> next) {
    this.next = next;
  }

  public DLNode<T> getPrevious() {
    return previous;
  }

  public void setPrevious(DLNode<T> previous) {
    this.previous = previous;
  }
}

/* Test Code
> DLNode<Integer> list = new DLNode<Integer>(1, null, null)
> DLNode<Integer> node2 = new DLNode<Integer>(2, list, null)
> DLNode<Integer> node3 = new DLNode<Integer>(3, node2, null)
> list.getElement()
1
> list.getNext().getElement()
2
> list.getNext().getNext().getElement()
3
> list.getPrevious()
null
> list.getNext().getPrevious().getElement()
1
> list.getNext().getNext().getPrevious().getElement()
2
*/
```

As I said before, I didn't ask this question with the expectation that one of you would do my homework for me. It would have been enough if somebody had just told me that I needed to make the nodes that my new nodes were pointing to also point back.